# How can I get round identity issues with Importing Access data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am figuring out how to migrate my data from an Access database to a SQL Server (2008 R2 Express Edition) one.  I was assuming that using Task->Import and loading data that way would be the way to go, but I have just hit a gotcha.

The data in the tables I am importing have autoincrement keys set, which I have to maintain as I load the data.  This is because there are (not enforced) foreign key references to the values.  I have now figured out that I have to create the tables within SQL Server with the IDENTITY option set and then use SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON for the table before importing.  Experiments show that the script (which I can't see) fails if this is required.

I have tried an experiment to create do something manually to display table "Prospect" the first attempt being

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Datasource="C:\Users\Alan\Documents\db\backend.mdb";Jet OLEDB:System Database="C:\Users\Alan\Documents\db\Secured.mdw";User ID=Alan;Password=xxxxxx;')...Prospect;
```

but this failed with the following

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Having found statements on the internet that suggested that this may be overcome using a different driver, I naively tried

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Datasource="C:\Users\Alan\Documents\db\beckendn.mdb";Jet OLEDB:System Database="C:\Users\Alan\Documents\db\Secured.mdw";User ID=Alan;Password=xxxxxx;')...Prospect;
```

but this also failed with ...

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

[Note: Whilst double checking this message I tried to import the table again into a fresh database and it failed to copy an entry.  It looks like an Access field of type Byte, with a non zero value in it (the copied table contains lots of entries with zero, but none of the non zero ones) to a field of type smallint caused an overflow error]

Comment: Does SQL Server is installed on 32 or 64bit OS?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the free software tool called the SQL Server Migration Assistant from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5abe098d-c7e1-46c6-994a-09a2856eef0b&displaylang=en

Comment: I tried this, and initially it looked good despite scarily updating my copy of Access in the process of installing itself.  It is great for pointing out slight inconsistencies in the database (primary keys with null values allowed for instance).  However, it is failing to actually copy any data, suggesting I might like to send the log file to product support.  I also haven't, as yet, figured out how to re-run a saved project either.

Comment: If it's not importing data, you must have uncorrected errors in the data. I find the SSMA a very good tool, as it allows you to simulate the import and find out what goes wrong so you can correct all the issues before running the real import. The only place it fails that I've noticed are on certain kinds of Access/Jet/ACE validation rules, which are easily edited to conform to the SQL Server format.

Comment: Yes, I found a date/time field with what looked like a corrupted time in it.

Comment: I actually took an alternative path, because I want to have as little thinking going on as possible, and I realise not quite everything needs importing directly (some config tables are different). So I use management studio to create a blank database and then use its task/import data to import the .mdb file into that. I then have a two stored procedures in the main database which copy the data over and insert it (with IDENTIY_INSERT on). 10 Minutes for the first (manual) stage, and 90 seconds for the second (automatic) stage